# Unable to refers listview on item button click using notfydatasetchange android

Tags: android

this is my Main class:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lead, container, false);


            prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            agentcode= prefs.getString(AppConstants.agentcode, "");


            listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);


            new LeadsBackground().execute();
            return rootView;
        }


        class LeadsBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setTitle("Searching");
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                try {
                    Response = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(Constants.LeadsURl + "AgentCode=" + agentcode);
                    JSONArray _jsonarray = new JSONArray(Response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < _jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject _jsobject = _jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DataModel datamodel = new DataModel();
                        datamodel.setJobNumber(_jsobject.getString("JobNumber"));
                        datamodel.setPhoneNumber(_jsobject.getString("PhoneNumber"));
                        datamodel.setCustomerName(_jsobject.getString("CustomerName"));
                        datamodel.setCustomerAddress(_jsobject.getString("CustomerAddress"));
                        datamodel.setCity(_jsobject.getString("City"));
                        datamodel.setPinCode(_jsobject.getString("PinCode"));
                        datamodel.setAppointmentDate(_jsobject.getString("AppointmentDate"));
                        datamodel.setAppointmentTime(_jsobject.getString("AppointmentTime"));

                        lstDataModel.add(datamodel);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


                  ListViewAdapter      listviewadapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.leadslistitem,
                        lstDataModel,agentcode);
                listview.setAdapter(listviewadapter);

                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

this is my adapter class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataModel> datamodel;

    String response;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //    LeadsFragment leads;
    String agentcode;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                           List<DataModel> worldpopulationlist, String agentcode) {
        super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);

        this.context = context;
        this.datamodel = worldpopulationlist;

        this.agentcode = agentcode;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView JobNumberTextView;
        TextView PhoneNumberTextView;
        TextView NameTextView;
        TextView AdressTextView;
        TextView DateTextView;

        ImageView acceptedbutton;
        ImageView rejectedbutton;

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leadslistitem, null);
            //
            holder.JobNumberTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            holder.PhoneNumberTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            holder.NameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.AdressTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            holder.DateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.acceptedbutton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

            holder.rejectedbutton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


//        Html.fromHtml("<b>Job No:</b> ")
        String sourceString = "<b>" + "JobNo:" + "</b> ";

        holder.JobNumberTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString) + datamodel.get(position).getJobNumber());
        holder.PhoneNumberTextView.setText(datamodel.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
        holder.NameTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Name   : ") + datamodel.get(position).getCustomerName());
        holder.AdressTextView.setText(datamodel.get(position).getCustomerAddress() + "," + datamodel.get(position).getCity() +
                "-" + datamodel.get(position).getPinCode());


        holder.DateTextView.setText(String.valueOf(Funcations.ConvertDatetime(datamodel.get(position).getAppointmentDate(), datamodel.get(position).getAppointmentTime()))

        );


        // Capture position and set to the TextViews

        holder.acceptedbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new AccepteRejectBackground().execute(datamodel.get(position).getJobNumber(), "true");

                sendBroadcaset(true);
            }

        });


        holder.rejectedbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                new AccepteRejectBackground().execute(datamodel.get(position).getJobNumber(), "false");
                sendBroadcaset(true);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    class AccepteRejectBackground extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setTitle("Searching");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

            response = HttpUtil.doGet(Constants.AcceptrejectURl + "AgentCode=" + agentcode + "&Jobid=" + strings[0] + "&response=" + strings[1]);

            String url = Constants.AcceptrejectURl + "AgentCode=" + agentcode + "&Jobid=" + strings[0] + "&response=" + strings[1];

            Log.e("Response", response);

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("1\n") || response.equals("1")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "NOt OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }


    private void sendBroadcaset(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                new Intent("update_boolean_variable").putExtra("action", b));
    }


}
```

i have two button accept and reject button i want to to refresh or update listview on Button click of  but my listview is not updating while i try to use notifydataset change but unable to refresh  while i ma getting data from server in Json Format on accept button and reject button i have to send parameter true false and respectively i have refresh listview please help me how i will do this

Comment: I hope you know about "." (full stop) and "," (commas), isnt it ? , 2 point is not worth for editing this post :-)

Answer (score 1):

For refreshing listview from the adapter, you need to call notifyDatasetChanged(). but in this manner.

```
AdapterClassName.this.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

For your class

```
ListViewAdapter.this.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: we have to call this in adapter class coz each button click on adapter